# SQL Query - Showing Max Outcome of a positive lead

Tags: sql

I need some help building a sql query to give me the results of all leads before the positive lead as well as the max postive lead.My qry is below with an example

```
SELECT        ContactHistory.Id, ProviderDetail.TimeStamp AS Date, ProviderDetail.FirstName AS CustomerName, ProviderDetail.CellNumber, AspNetUsers.FirstName AS Agentname, ProviderOutcome.Outcome, 
                         ProviderOutcome.Status, ProviderDetail.ProviderAgentName, SourceType.Name AS ProviderName, ContactHistory.Timestamp
FROM            ProviderOutcome RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         AspNetUsers RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         SourceType RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         ProviderDetail LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         ContactHistory ON ProviderDetail.CellNumber = ContactHistory.CellNumber ON SourceType.Pk = ProviderDetail.ProviderId ON AspNetUsers.Id = ContactHistory.UserId ON 
                         ProviderOutcome.Id = ContactHistory.OutcomeId
WHERE        (NOT (ProviderOutcome.Outcome LIKE 'Application started')) AND (SourceType.Name LIKE N'%Edu Power%') AND (ProviderDetail.TimeStamp >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-10-18 00:00:00', 102)) AND 
                         (ProviderDetail.CellNumber = '0605775234')
ORDER BY ContactHistory.Timestamp
```

EXAMPLE OF TABLE

```
ID   NAME  OUTCOME     DATE
1    JOHN  FAILED      1st Jan
2    JANE  SALE        1st Jan
3    JOCK  NO ANSWER   2nd Jan
4    JESS  SALE        2nd Jan
5    JACK  DUPLICATE   3rd Jan
```

So i want to display all data and stop at the last sale outcome which is Jess and not show anything after that,so Jack wont display in my results

PLease help

Comment: RIGHT OUTER JOIN...?!? Most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.